# calculate the speed of a ball, with a laser

Tags: physics

I'm doing a project where I have to calculate the speed of a ball, passing a certain point.

I want to do this with a laser, by taking the time the laser is broken in comparison of the ball it's size.

Someone who can help me with the correct formula?

Comment: That seems to be a rather unreliable way of measuring speed. If you don't _already_ have extremely fine control of the velocity of the ball, how can you be sure that the _center_ of the ball will travel exactly through your laster beam? If it doesn't, you will measure too short a time (and thus get too high a speed).

Comment: Are you assuming that the ball is moving at a constant speed in a straight line, and its center exactly passing through the laser beam?

Answer (score 0):

The laser will "draw" a line segment of *apparent* length $l$ on the bullet, during time $t$.

The exact formula is

$$v_\perp=\frac lt,$$ where $v_\perp$ denotes the component of the *average* speed perpendicular to the beam.

Comment: As commented by others, determining $l$ can be problematic. (*Apparent* means projected on a plane perpendicular to the beam.)